# I try to use full potential of my display, but it seems like connectors don’t want to

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport

**Context:**

I have bought a 34" ultra-wide 100Hz 2K display (AOC 34" LED - CU34P2A).

I have a 2019 MacBook Pro 13" running Big Sur with 2 Thunderbolt 3 ports.

For work, I have a top-level Dell laptop with HDMI.

AOC display has 2 HDMI and 1 DisplayPort input.

**Issue:**

Connecting directly to my Windows laptop with HDMI uses the full potential of this display: 3440 x 1440p and 100Hz frame rate.

Connecting the AOC to my Mac using a hub (Thunderbolt 3 -> hub’s HDMI -> display’s HDMI input) sadly gives a poor (and blurry) image: 2560 x 1080p and a maximum 60Hz frame rate.

What I need is to get same resolution and frame rate I see using the Windows laptop.

I have a free Thunderbolt output on the Mac.
I know Thunderbolt 3 is compatible to DisplayPort 1.2 but I don’t know if DP 1.2 allows 3440 x 1440 at least at 60Hz (or more if possible, up to 100HZ). In fact, frame rate isn’t a priority.

Could I plug a Thunderbolt 3 to DisplayPort and plug this last to the display using this dongle?
https://www.startech.com/en-us/audio-video-products/cdp2dp14ucpb

Do you have any idea of how to fix this issue? Do not hesitate to ask for more details, if needed!

Comment: What happens if you plug directly, without using the hub? Are the HDMI cables v2.0? Are you using the same cable with the Dell?

Comment: I don't know how to plug Thunderbolt 3 to HDMI/DisplayPort without using a dongle (hub here), so I didn't try.

There's anything written on the HDMI but I have tried with high end HDMI cable (https://monsterstore.fr/cables-hdmi/110-cable-hdmi-monster-essentials-ultra-hd-4k-0050644766381.html) and it's not working (with mac). I tried the same cable with the Dell and it works. The issue seems to be at the level of the Hub, or the Mac itself.

Comment: Sounds like you need to rule out the hub, by connecting the Mac directly, with the correct cable/adaptor.

Comment: Ok, I will try your suggestion and buy the following adaptor, or a better one if you know a famous and reliable adaptor for my need. [link to adaptor](https://www.startech.com/en-us/audio-video-products/cdp2dp14ucpb)

Comment: Why not just buy a USB C/Thunderbolt to DisplayPort cable?

Comment: This seems like a better idea ! Avoiding adaptors is avoiding problems.. Now I will find a good one and see how it works.

Comment: It works ! 3440 x 1440 and 100Hz (which I did not expect) using a standard USB-C to DP 1.2 cable. Thank you.